# Service with Async Task isn't starting

Tags: android, asynchronous, foreground-service

I'm using the below code to start a service. this service should start Async task that checks mysql and provide notifications. the service isn't starting and I can't find why? I receive no Log from the service.
(when I call the Async task from main activity directly without service it works fine).

Main Activity code:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
MainActivity.this.startService(startIntent);
```

Service Class Code:

```
 public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "On Create");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "On Start");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String newoperator = "Go";
                TimeSync ReportCheck= new TimeSync(getApplicationContext());
                ReportCheck.execute(newoperator);
            }

        }).start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

I also found some solutions adding the below command in main activity but the command isn't applicable in my android studio.

```
startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
```

Comment: check the following: 1. service is declared in manifest 2. the log in the onStartCommand gets printed 3. Log in the onCreate gets printed

Comment: Perfect, I had to problems, the first I wasn't declaring the service in the mainifest file, the second that I was making the service class impeded in MainActivityClass. I moved it to a separate class and it works :) thanks

Comment: great :) glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

What version of android studio do you use? Have you tried to updated to the latest version?

[Download Android Studio 2.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#win-bundle)

Comment: I have the latest one, problem solved by declaring the service in the Manifests file. thanks